# Tornado Websockets Demo not working on OpenShift

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, openshift, tornado

I am trying to get the [Tornado Websockets Demo](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/tree/master/demos/websocket)  running on OpenShift. I am starting from a Python2.7 cartridge.

Within app.py, I bind to the OpenShift provided python port and python IP address. The code deploys without any issues and I can go to my site and view the static files and the index. Within my client, I make sure to connect to the OpenShift standard websocket port (8000).

However, I cannot send or receive data. Whenever I attempt to send a message, the following error appears in my browser console:

> WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED
>   state.

I've included the relevant sections of code below:

## app.py

```
import ...

ON_PAAS = 'OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR' in os.environ

if ON_PAAS:
    port = int(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_PORT'])
    host = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_IP']
    debug = False
    dir_virtualenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
    virtualenv = os.path.join(dir_virtualenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
        try:
            execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
        except IOError:
            pass
else:
    port = 8000
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    debug = True        

define("port", default=port, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("host", default=host, help="run on the given host", type=str)
define("debug", default=debug, help="run in debug mode")

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/chatsocket", ChatSocketHandler),
        ]
        settings = dict(
            cookie_secret="__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
            template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
            xsrf_cookies=True,
        )
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    ...

class ChatSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    ...

def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = Application()
    app.listen(options.port, address=options.host)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## chat.js

```
...

var updater = {
    socket: null,

    start: function() {
        var url = "ws://" + location.host + ":8000/chatsocket";
        updater.socket = new WebSocket(url);
        updater.socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            updater.showMessage(JSON.parse(event.data));
        }
    },

    showMessage: function(message) {
        var existing = $("#m" + message.id);
        if (existing.length > 0) return;
        var node = $(message.html);
        node.hide();
        $("#inbox").append(node);
        node.slideDown();
    }
};
```

EDIT: [I assume that OpenShift supports WebSockets.](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/) The documentation isn't very thorough though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose to start fresh without using the Tornado websocket chat demo. I've created a public github repository with the necessary code to allow for functional websockets.

https://github.com/awwong1/django-tornado-websockets-openshift

Comment: So, did you identify what the issue was? Your question is titled "Tornado Websockets Demo not working on OpenShift" -- did you provide an answer to that? ;)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, OpenShift allows incoming TCP connections only on ports 22 and 443. I think you cannot change this. Make your WebSocket server listen on 443, too (instead of 8000). That is the great thing: WebSocket is an upgrade to HTTP -- your web application and your websocket server can run on the same port. Your web server just needs be informed, that normal HTTP requests are to be delegated to your "normal" web application, and HTTP UPGRADE requests are to be delegated to your WebSocket server.

Edit:

I have a hard time to find **official** documentation about the ports which are allowed to use with OpenShift. From the article you mentioned, you are right, 8000 and 8443 should work:

> ```
> http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTP URL
> http://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8000/ <= WebSockets enables HTTP URL
>
> https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com/  <= your current HTTPs URL
> https://app-lovingwebsockets.rhcloud.com:8443/ <= WebSockets enables HTTPs URL
> ```

However, this is a *blog post*, not official documentation, and it is from 2012. A lot might have changed since then! You should go ahead and try to find official documentation about using WebSockets on OpenShift, really.

Did you properly install a `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler`-derived instance as the handler for the `chatsocket` route? You do not show this in your code.

Comment: Openshift has websocket support since 2012, according to [this OpenShift blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/).

Comment: I properly installed the `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` instance as the handler for the chatsocket route. I will edit the code snippet above to show this. Although I'm certain that I performed all of the steps correctly, you're correct about this being unofficial documentation. Official WebSocket documentation on OpenShift doesn't seem to exist, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if client and server runs on the sane open shift app it works, if the client is moved to my PC I experience the same behaviour, connect and suddenly receive a disconnect from the server. But do not know why.